# Jenkins declarative pipeline: if-else statement inside parameters directive

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to display a choice parameter if I have options to choose from, or else display an input text, something like this (which does not work):

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
       if (someOptions) {
          choice(name: 'FIELD_NAME', choices: "$someOptions", description: 'Field description')
       } else {
          string(name: 'FIELD_NAME', defaultValue: '', description: 'Field description')
       }
    }

    environment {
      // environment params
    }

    stages {
      // stages
    }
}
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: For this level of robustness in input parameters, you would likely need the Active Choice plugin and wrapping `parameters` inside of `properties`.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Matt Schuchard's comment, here's what this might look like:

```
def my_param = []

if (someOptions) {
     my_param = [$class: 'ChoiceParameter',
            name: 'FIELD_NAME',
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            description: 'Choose the desired option',
            script:
                [$class: 'GroovyScript',
                  fallbackScript:
                    [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: 'return ""'],
                  script:
                    [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: "return $someOptions"]
                ]
            ]
} else {
    my_param = [$class: 'StringParameterDefinition',
            name: 'FIELD_NAME',
            defaultValue: false,
            description: '']
}

properties([
    parameters([my_param,
          // other parameters
```

Don't forget to approve Groovy scripts in script approval console.

Comment: In which part of the script I gave as example should this snippet go? or does the script have to follow a different structure?

Comment: This goes before `pipeline {`, but you need to move all parameters to the `properties` section.